# How to do input login check by using php and ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to create length login check script, validating every time when you change something in input. So response from php should be deliver all time when you change value in the input. I can't do it. In my script it is validate when i change something in input, but aditionally i have to masue out from input. How to do it when i just writing something in input? Please help... Should i use interval function in js?

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

<input name='login'>
<div>empty</div>
<button>Kliknij</button>


<script >
    var loginField =document.querySelector('input');
    var loginValue = document.querySelector('input').value.length;
    console.log(loginValue);
    var btN = document.querySelector('button');
    loginField.addEventListener('change', pokazListe);
    //window.onload = pokazListe();
    function pokazListe(){
        var loginValue = document.querySelector('input').value.length;
        var zapytanie = "";
        zapytanie = new XMLHttpRequest();
        zapytanie.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(zapytanie.readyState==4 && zapytanie.status==200){
                document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = zapytanie.responseText;
            }
            else{
                document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'not work';
            }
        }
        zapytanie.open("GET","data.php?login="+loginValue,true);
        zapytanie.send();
    }

</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

and here is php code

```
<?php

$login = ($_GET['login']);

if($login < 6 || $login > 12 )
{
    echo "Login has to have 6 to 12 charts"." ".$login;
}
else
{
    echo "Login is ok."." ".$login;
}


?>
```

Comment: Try and use the `keydown` or `keyup` event instead of `change` (which only gets triggered when the element loses focus).

Answer (score 0):

your code is quite bad design imo.

the way to do validation is to make sure the input length is within the min. max before trigger web service/api.

use input for event listener, so it will fire for every input in the input box:

```
loginField.addEventListener('input', pokazListe);
```

in your function:

```
function pokazListe(){
    var loginValue = document.querySelector('input');
    if(loginValue.value.length >= 6 && loginValue.value.length <= 12) {
        var zapytanie = "";
        zapytanie = new XMLHttpRequest();
        zapytanie.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(zapytanie.readyState==4 && zapytanie.status==200){
                document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = zapytanie.responseText;
            }
            else{
                document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'not work';
            }
        }
        zapytanie.open("GET","data.php?login="+loginValue,true);
        zapytanie.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: additionally, if you want to put other text such as "your input too short", just add another 'else if' in that function, if (length < 6) {document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'too short';}